# C decryption program - Heap corruption detected

Tags: c, string, encryption

I'm trying to write a very simple code.

Basically, I get an "encrypted" string from the user, and my code decrypts it with the following rule:

"From the first letter of the string subtract one, from the second subtract 2, from the third subtract 3 and so on. Spaces stay unchanged"

I wrote this code:

```
char* q4(char* str_in)
{
    char* str_out;
    int str_out_length,i,temp;
    str_out_length=strlen(str_in)+1; //+1 for null terminator
    str_out=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*str_out_length);
    str_out[str_out_length]='\0'; //null terminator at last index
    for(i=0;i<str_out_length;i++)
    {
        if(str_in[i]!=' ')
        {
            temp=str_in[i];
            str_out[i]=(char)(temp-i-1);
        }
        else
            str_out[i]=str_in[i];
    }
    return str_out;
}
```

My code seems to return incorrect output, and not only that, I also have an error that reads "Heap Corruption detected".

For example, when the string i input is `Btwlzx Dqqes`, the output is `Arthur <hgZg<=` and an error. Basically the first word is correct. The second one is rubbish. And if I enter just `Btwlzx`, then the output is `Arthur-` and said error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str_out_length=strlen(str_in)+1; //+1 for null terminator
str_out=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*str_out_length);
```

It seems that the terminator is placed one byte behind the allocated buffer. Try

```
str_out[str_out_length - 1]='\0';
```

And similarly, perhaps

```
for(i=0;i<str_out_length;i++)
```

should be

```
for(i=0;i<str_out_length-1;i++)
```

---

Or, maybe better, change

```
str_out_length=strlen(str_in)+1; //+1 for null terminator
str_out=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*str_out_length);
```

with

```
str_out_length=strlen(str_in);
str_out=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(str_out_length+1)); //+1 for null terminator
```

and then use `str_out_length` without `-1`-correction.

---

**Update** (after reading the comment)

```
print_decrypted("Btwlzx Dqqes Eq|pj2 Tjhvqujs Iqoqjy bpg Eqfxtx Xcwwtt");
```

outputs

> Arthur Conan Doyle, Sherlock Holmes and Doctor Watson

```
void print_decrypted(char* str)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    if (str[i] != ' ')
    {
        printf("%c", str[i] - k - 1);
        k++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" ");
        k = 0;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Yes I see, this was the problem. Thanks its working now. At any rate, it seems like the text I was asked to decrypt is gibberish. The first word is Arthur, but the second word makes no sense. I was asked to decrypt "Btwlzx Dqqes Eq|pj2 Tjhvqujs Iqoqjy bpg Eqfxtx Xcwwtt"

Comment: @OriaGruber I tried to reset the counter at spaces. Then I got "_Arthur Conan Doyle, Sherlock Holmes and Doctor Watson_".